# FlexLayout on Xamarin forms, not filled items behaviour?

Tags: ios, user-interface, xamarin.forms

I have created a simple page with Flexlayout. As expected, the items are spaced evenly in each row but not equally in the second row if there are empty items in the row. 
As you can see on this image:

[image: FlexLayout uneven item number issue]

Here is the code that i used:

```
 <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="0.1*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="0.8*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="0.1*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <StackLayout Grid.Row="0">
        <Label Text="Header Stacklayout Label" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
    </StackLayout>
    <ScrollView  Grid.Row="1" HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Start">
        <FlexLayout Direction="Row" AlignItems="Start" JustifyContent="SpaceEvenly" Wrap="Wrap" >
            <Label Text="FlexLayout" FontSize="Large" WidthRequest="120" HeightRequest="50" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" BackgroundColor="Silver"/>
            <Label Text="FlexLayout" FontSize="Large" WidthRequest="120" HeightRequest="50" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" BackgroundColor="Silver"/>
            <Label Text="FlexLayout" FontSize="Large" WidthRequest="120" HeightRequest="50" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" BackgroundColor="Silver"/>
            <Label Text="FlexLayout" FontSize="Large" WidthRequest="120" HeightRequest="50" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" BackgroundColor="Silver"/>
            <Label Text="FlexLayout" FontSize="Large" WidthRequest="120" HeightRequest="50" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" BackgroundColor="Silver"/>

        </FlexLayout>
    </ScrollView>
    <StackLayout Grid.Row="2">
        <Label Text="Footer Stacklayout Label" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
    </StackLayout>
</Grid>
```

I am expecting the expecting the items to be spaced evenly but also equally between all rows. The last 2 items should be aligned to the left and one empty space for an item should be at the end. I believe this is how it's implemented in Bootstrap and similar systems.

Comment: Can someone please help?
The answer below is not dynamic and will work on one screen size only

Answer (score 1):

If you want to achieve the view like following screenshot 
[image]

Just set the value of `JustifyContent` as `Start`

```
<FlexLayout Direction="Row" AlignItems="Start" JustifyContent="Start" Wrap="Wrap" >
  <Label Text="FlexLayout" FontSize="Large" WidthRequest="120" HeightRequest="50" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" BackgroundColor="Silver"/>
  <Label Text="FlexLayout" FontSize="Large" WidthRequest="120" HeightRequest="50" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" BackgroundColor="Silver"/>
  <Label Text="FlexLayout" FontSize="Large" WidthRequest="120" HeightRequest="50" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" BackgroundColor="Silver"/>
  <Label Text="FlexLayout" FontSize="Large" WidthRequest="120" HeightRequest="50" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" BackgroundColor="Silver"/>
  <Label Text="FlexLayout" FontSize="Large" WidthRequest="120" HeightRequest="50" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" BackgroundColor="Silver"/>
</FlexLayout>
```

For more detail about `JustifyContent` you can access [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/flex-layout)

Comment: Thanks for your response, I tried this but as you can see, i am not able to center the whole content

Comment: It will be justified to the start of the parent 
I tried different options like HorizentalOptions in every Layout

Comment: I am required to have the same design as in your answer but the whole Flex layout should be centered. Distance from both sides should be equal.

Comment: This is because of you set the value of WidthRequest .Try to set the value as 1/3 of the width of screen

Comment: I will appreciate it if you can guide me to that. If i set it up from the code behind, i believe it will give me the same result. If you read the description of JustifyContent with Start option, it says "Start of the parent" while i want the contents to start from left but the whole thing to be centered like in my image

Comment: in my answer, the sizing is perfect, it's just that if the items are not filling the row, it will not be ordered as the above row. but it will center itself equally in that row.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what i wanted to achieve. Can you kindly explain what you did to center the whole thing?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182063/discussion-between-lucas-zhang-msft-and-ali123).